# Mi input tipo time no se llena automáticamente con php

Tags: php, date

estoy intentando llenar un input tipo time con la hora actual de esta manera:

```
<?php 
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Bogota');

$hora=date("g:i A");
?>
```

Y de esta forma estoy llenando el input con el dato de hora:

```
<input type="time" name="horafin" value="<?php echo $hora;?>" />
```

Pero no llena el campo, ya probé cambio el tipo de input por un type=text y si funciona perfecto, pero necesito necesariamente que se llene con el input time.

De que forma podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero ayudarte.

Es por que en el formato estas especificando si es AM o PM con `A`, quitalo y funcionará, y especifica que el formato sea 24 horas con ceros iniciales con `H`.

Código de ejemplo:

```
<?php 
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Bogota');

$hora=date("H:i");
?>
```

Explicacion formato de función `date`:

- `H` -> Formato de 24 horas de una hora con ceros iniciales (0 hasta 23).
- `i` -> Minutos con ceros iniciales (00 hasta 59).

Lo que tenias especificado:

- `g` -> Formato de 12 horas de una hora sin ceros iniciales (1 a 12).
- `A` -> Ante meridiem y Post meridiem en mayúsculas (AM o PM).

Fuente: [PHP:date manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

Comment: me funciono perfecto muchas gracias.